# Use ARCore to detect marker and show information

Tags: java, android, game-design, augmented-reality, prototyping

I'm new to AR, and am trying to use Google's ARCore to build a simple AR prototype. Basically if a logo is detected, I like to place some real-time charts or text information on the screen. Similar to **[this demo](https://github.com/viromedia/virocore/blob/master/ARTesla/viro_car_marker_demo.gif)** for placing a car on a logo using other SDKs.

Am I able to do this in ARCore (with Android Studio)? Is there any samples or examples showcasing similar concept?

Comment: Presumably you've already read the documentation on [AR Core Augmented Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/) and investigated the [Augmented Images sample app linked there](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmented_image_java)? Have you run into any particular trouble understanding this sample or developing your app with this information? If so, please edit your question to detail exactly where you're running into trouble and users here can try to help you solve that specific problem.

Comment: No I didn't know about that sample. I am using another library which is a bit higher layer on top of ARCore.

Comment: That would also be a useful detail to add to your question then. ;)